# I want to extend the CoreDataBooks example with a UIPickerView

Tags: core-data, nsarray, uipickerview

I am trying to add in a third method into the editting view controller in this example; a simple pickerview for a field.  Currently, my pickerview has 6 items that I load into it.  When I run it, it shows a '?' for the value on the picker view rather than the word.  It does select the right item/row and return it to the calling controller, but it just won't display the text.

I believe that I am not allocating the array properly to the PickerView as it compiles with the following warning:

```
"Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'Struct NArrary *', expected 'struct UIPickerView *'"
```

Here is what I have declared in the .h file:

```
 UIPickerView *pickerView;
 NSArray *choiceArray;


 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *choiceArray;
```

And in the .m file:

```
  choiceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Financial",@"One",@"Two",@"three",@"four",@"six", nil];
  pickerView = choiceArray; //<-- error
  [choiceArray release];
```

It's this line:  "pickerView = choiceArray;"
that I get the warning on.

thx,
wes

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the array to the pickerView attribute itself. Your are doing this:

```
(UIPickerView*)pickerView = (NSArray*)choiceArray;
```

You actually assign the rows of a picker view from its delegate which is an object that implements the [UIPickerViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html).